# Unable to redirect to a jsp page using Model and view in Spring

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

Hi i want to redirect to a jsp page using Model and view but not able to get that page.Below is the code can any one help me on this?

```
public ModelAndView login(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws GridException {
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("json view");
    Map map = new HashMap();
    GridMappingVO gridMappingVO=new GridMappingVO();
    String users = request.getParameter("username");
    String passwrd = request.getParameter("password");
    gridMappingVO.setUser(users);
    gridMappingVO.setPass(passwrd);
    List<GridMappingVO> searchList= gridMappingFacade.validate(gridMappingVO);
    if(users.equals(searchList.get(0).getUser()) && passwrd.equals(searchList.get(0).getPass())){
        System.out.println("validation succesfull");
        mv = new ModelAndView("searchResults");
        mv.addObject("searchList", searchList);

    }
    else{
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("Invalid");
        map.put("error_messages", list);
        mv.addAllObjects(map);
    }





    return mv;

}
```

}

*This the spring config which am using
    
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

```
      <import resource="datasource-config.xml"/>
      <import resource="dao-config.xml"/>


<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">

    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
    </property>

    <property name="suffix">
    <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>

</bean>
    <bean id="xmlFileViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.XmlViewResolver">
        <property name="order" value="2" />
        <property name="location" value="/WEB-INF/views.xml" />
    </bean>

<bean name="/*.html" class="com.dashboard.web.controller.GridMappingController" scope="request">
    <property name="gridMappingFacade" ref="gridMappingFacade"/>
</bean> 

<bean id="gridMappingFacade" class="com.dashboard.web.application.GridMappingFacadeImpl">
    <property name="gridMappingService" ref="gridMappingService" />     
</bean>

<bean id="gridMappingService" class="com.dashboard.web.service.GridMappingServiceImpl">
    <property name="gridMappingRepository" ref="gridMappingRepository" />       
</bean> 

</beans>*
```

Comment: Can you post your spring config? What do you see in the logs when you enable debbug logging? Do you get any exceptions?

Comment: i have added the spring config file

Comment: mmm I think there might be around 100 causes why it doesn't work. I suggest you to download [this](https://github.com/augusto/bdd-presentation/tree/master/exercise) project from github and compare the configuration files with your own files. The project is a tiny sample app that I use to demonstrate how to do BDD.

Comment: Try looking at the TRACE/DEBUG logs for org.springframework.web you might be able to see what is going wrong. Without any stack traces we won't be able to help.

Comment: @Alex how can i do this trace/debug logs? I don't know how to do it

Comment: reference to view with name 'searchResults'; model is null

Answer (score 0):

use this code to redirect page

```
 mv.setViewName("searchResults");
```